# error when applying function with dplyr mutate

Tags: r, dplyr

```
df <- data.frame(x=c(1,2,3,4),y=c(5,6,7,8), w=c(9,10,11,12))

fun <- function (x) (colMeans(x)**2)
```

I'm getting an error when I try this:

```
df %>% mutate_at(c("x","y"), fun)

! Problem with `mutate()` column `x`.
i `x = (function (x) ...`.
x 'x' must be an array of at least two dimensions
Caused by error in `base::wMeans()`:
! 'x' must be an array of at least two dimensions
Run `rlang::last_trace()` to see where the error occurred.
```

How can I apply a function that uses `colMeans`?

Comment: In this case use `mean`. It will do the same as `colMeans(df[c("x", "y"])`. A `dplyr` way with `colMeans` is `df %>% select(x, y) %>% fun`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`colMeans()` expects a matrix as input.
With `mutate(across...` we pass a dataframe with two columns to `my_fun`.
One way to overcome this is to modify the function so the dataframe is converted to a matrix:

```
library(dplyr)

my_fun <- function(df) {
  mat <- as.matrix(df)
  colMeans(mat)**2
}

df %>%
  mutate(across(c(x, y), my_fun))

   x     y  w
1 6.25 42.25  9
2 6.25 42.25 10
3 6.25 42.25 11
4 6.25 42.25 12
```

Answer (score 1):

We could use `.colMeans` with `m` and `n`

```
fun <- function (x) (.colMeans(x, m = length(x), n = 1)**2)
df %>%
   mutate(across(c(x, y), fun))
     x     y  w
1 6.25 42.25  9
2 6.25 42.25 10
3 6.25 42.25 11
4 6.25 42.25 12
```